# Python Pandas Error tokenizing data: How to avoid error caused by different length

Tags: python, pandas, tokenize

I am trying to read a *.dat file with pandas read_csv function.

```
df = pd.read_csv(file, skiprows=0, header=None, sep=" ", parse_dates=[[0, 1]])
```

The data looks like this:

```
2019-06-01 04:00:22 PW  100  2000  2000 /// // // // ////// ////// ////
2019-06-01 04:00:32 PW  100  2000  2000 /// // // // ////// ////// ////
2019-06-01 04:00:42 PW  100  2000  2000 /// // // // ////// ////// ////
2019-06-01 04:00:52 PW  100  2000  2000 /// // // // ////// ////// ////
2019-06-01 04:01:02 PW  100  2000  2000 /// // // // ////// ////// ////
2019-06-01 04:01:12 PW  100  2000  2000 /// // // // ////// ////// ////
2019-06-01 04:01:22 PW  100  2000  2000 /// // // // ////// ////// ////
2019-06-01 04:01:32 PW  100  2000  2000 /// // // // ////// ////// ////
```

I get a Tokenizing Error:

```
ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 16 fields in line 242, saw 17
```

I think this error is caused, because in line 242 the values in column 6 are lower than in the lines before, e.g. column 6 stays at 2000 or has values with 4 digits (e.g. 1501), but in line 242 it drops to 991 (three digits).

```
2019-06-01 04:39:32 PW  100  2000  2000 /// // // // ////// ////// ////
2019-06-01 04:39:42 PW  100  1501  2000 /// // // // ////// ////// ////
2019-06-01 04:39:52 PW  100  1501  2000 /// // // // ////// ////// ////
2019-06-01 04:40:02 PW  100  1501  2000 /// // // // ////// ////// ////
2019-06-01 04:40:12 PW  100  1187  2000 /// // // // ////// ////// ////
2019-06-01 04:40:22 PW  100  1187  2000 /// // // // ////// ////// ////
2019-06-01 04:40:32 PW  100   991  2000 /// // // // ////// ////// ////
```

How can I get rid of this error?

error_bad_lines=False is not an option, because I need exactly these values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `sep=" +"` or `sep="\s+"` instead of `sep=" "`. With the latter, multiple blanks are separated into multiple empty columns which causes the error when the number of blanks changes.

As an alternative, you could specifiy `delim_whitespace=True` instead of `sep` or `delimiter`.

Comment: Thank you so much!! By adding sep=" +" it works perfectly fine! I was not aware of this. You saved me a lot of time! Thank you very much